# Show/hide toggle using Jquery .click, works with new users, but not seeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to use Jquery to hide/show links targeting the div id and using .click.  When the page loads, I hide the edit buttons, and the cancel button using javascript.  When I click Edit your profile link, I target the edit_button class which should display the buttons.

I am not sure why it works  half of the time.  When I edit the user profile of existing seeds(that I created), the hide/show doesn't work at all, but when I create a new user, Jquery works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

profile.html.erb

```
<div class="profile_information">
    <%= render partial: 'profileinformation', locals: {user: @user} %>
</div>
    <h3 class="edit", id = "show_edit_button"><%= link_to "Edit your profile", :remote => :true  %></h3>
    <h3 class='edit', id="cancel_edit_button"><%= link_to "Cancel", :remote => :true  %></h3>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready page:load', function(){
        $(".edit_button").hide();
        $('#cancel_edit_button').hide();
    });

</script>
```

_profile.html.erb

```
<h3>Location:</h3>
<div class="location">
  <p id = "location"><%= @user.location %></p>
</div>
<div class = "edit_button", id = "edit_location_button">
  <%= link_to "Edit Location", :remote => :true  %>
</div>

<h3>Biography:</h3>
<div class = "biography">
  <p id = "biography"><%= @user.biography %></p>
</div>
<div class="edit_button" id ="edit_biography_button">
   <%= link_to "Edit Biography", :remote => :true  %>
</div>

<h3>Experience:</h3>
  <div class="experience">
    <p class="info" id="experience"><%= @user.experience %></p>
  </div>

<div class = "edit_button", id ="edit_experience_button">
  <%= link_to "Edit Experience", :remote => :true  %>
</div>
```

profile.js.erb

```
$("#show_edit_button").click(function() {
  $('.edit_button').show();
  $('#cancel_edit_button').show();
  $('#show_edit_button').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
$button = $('#show_edit_button');

$button.on('click', function() {
    $('.edit_button').show();
    $('#cancel_edit_button').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion.  Works when I create a new user, but when I am trying to edit an existing seed that I created, the buttons won't show but the jquery request goes through.  Any ideas on why this might be the case?